# Confirm to Equatable for Custom struct

Tags: ios, swift

I have below kind of response model, where the body is decided by another variable. How can i confirm equatable to this Model

```
public struct Model {
    let type: String? // can be type1 or type2
    let body: ResponseType?
}

protocol ResponseType: Codable {

}


struct Response1: ResponseType {
    var items: [String]?
}


struct Response2: ResponseType {
    var item: String?
}
```

What i want to achive:

```
 extension Model: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
        // How to equate the body?
    }
}
```

When im trying to add Equatable to ResponseType protocol it says below error.
`Protocol 'ResponseType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: You may want to consider updating your sample code to be valid Swift (see your protocol definition and your re-definition of `Response1`), lest the eager downvoters get ahold of this.

Comment: You should realize that `ResponseType` must be `Equatable` too. However, once it's equatable, you can use it only as a constraint and that will force your `Model` to be generic: `Model<T: ResponseType>` with `body: T?`. And then it will be automatically equatable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `==` manually. swift doesn't know that `body` can only be two types, which are?

```
public struct Model: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
        if lhs.type != rhs.type {
            return false
        }
        if let lhsBody = lhs.body as? Response1, let rhsBody = rhs.body as? Response1 {
            return lhsBody == rhsBody
        } else if let lhsBody = lhs.body as? Response2, let rhsBody = rhs.body as? Response2 {
            return lhsBody == rhsBody
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    let type: String? // can be type1 or type2
    let body: ResponseType?
}

protocol ResponseType: Codable {

}


struct Response1: ResponseType, Equatable {
    var items: [String]?
}


struct Response2: ResponseType, Equatable {
    var item: String?
}
```

It might be easier if you change `Model` into an `enum`:

```
enum Model: Codable, Equatable {
    case type1(items: [String]?)
    case type2(item: String)

    var type: String {
        switch self {
        case .type1: return "type1"
        case .type2: return "type2"
        }
    }
}
```

You probably need to change the `Codable` implementation so that it encodes and decodes the way you want to.

Comment: tried this, but any changes inside the body is not taken by differencekit framework, since there is no actual link between them.

Comment: @Saranjith `body` is declared a `let` here, so I'm not sure how you are going to change it at all...? You are probably just changing a copy of `body`. Make sure `body` is a `var` and make sure that you are reassigning `body` or using a mutating thing on `body`, and not a copy of it.

Comment: No. im not changing it, its from api response, DifferenceKit used for finding difference between two array of models, they takes Equatable model as input and gives ChangeSet

Comment: @Saranjith Can you show a [mcve]? Also show the actual output vs what you expect to be output.